# Abelianness-forcing number Q

Tags: functions, number-theory, algebra

In the theory of finite abstract group, abelianness-forcing number $n$ is characterized as a positive integer with standard factorization $n=p_1^{k_1}p_2^{k_2}\cdots p_r^{k_r}$ with $k_i \le 2$ and $p_i$ does not divide $p_j^{k_j}-1$ for any $1 \le i,j \le r$. I want to define a function "AbeliannessForcingNumberQ" which returns "True" if and only if the argument is a abeliannes-forcing number. But I cannot figure out how to deal with prime factors and exponents in a given number.
Please help to define this function.

Comment: The following is an external link for the corresponding mathematical concept.
https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Abelianness-forcing_number

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
abeliannessForcingNumberQ[n_Integer] := And @@ Flatten[{
   Table[Not@Divisible[Power @@ p - 1, q], {p, FactorInteger[n]}, {q, First /@ FactorInteger[n]}], 
   Thread[Last /@ FactorInteger[n] <= 2]
   }]

Select[Range[20], abeliannessForcingNumberQ]
(* 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19 *)
```

See also [A051532](http://oeis.org/A051532).

Comment: What a quick and exact response!

Comment: As a minor correction, we should include $1$ as an abelianness forcing number.